# obtaining console output as a parameter or a variable in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using a python script from the git repo. I want to build the script in jenkins and obtain the console output values as a parameter so that I can pass it to a downstream job. I could not find a proper answer through out google. Is there any possible way?
Is there any way to obtain the console output values of a job in jenkins? I want to obtain the console output values as parameter and pass it to another job! Please help me out! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use `output = sh(script: '<cmd to build the python script>', returnOutstd: true).trim()` to get the output of any cmd, then assign to a Groovy variable.

Then you can call the downstream job in current Jenkinsfile via `build job: '', parameters: []`